# No matching Provisioning profiles allowing aps (But there is a provisioning profile that should allow it)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, provisioning-profile

---

I've been working on creating a release for an application (for iOS) I am working on but it seems like the transition between debugging and release is harder than I imagined. In Development, I was able to build successfully but now that I have switched over to a release version, it keeps coming back with 1 error and 2 warnings;

---

No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: aps-environment.

iOS deployment target '11.1' for architecture 'arm64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '9.3.99' for the iOS 9.3 SDK.

iOS deployment target '11.1' for architecture 'arm64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '9.3.99' for the iOS 9.3 SDK.

---

I presume this has something to do with the Provising Profiles needing to be in the Production form which you can do so on the developer App Store. I did this already and I am aware that the aps stands for the Apple Push Services. I did so but I seem to get the same error everytime so I either have done something wrong.

I have narrowed down some details that may be helpful but if not I apologies:

- The Provising profile and the application have the same bundle identifier and Team assigned to it.
- The Provising Profile has Push Notifications enabled.
- Xcode Version 7 (Swift 2) <- I may be well aware that this might be the issue, would I really have to convert from 2 to 3 then from 3 to 4 because I feel that would be really time consuming.
- Cordova was used to generate the project.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you generating provisioning profile & certificate manually OR automatically through xcode ?

Comment: The issue is now solved but for your interest, I was generating them outside of xcode from the developer site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there could be a couple things going wrong.

- iOS deployment target '11.1' for architecture 'arm64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '9.3.99' for the iOS 9.3 SDK

This error is usually caused by setting the wrong `<preference name="deployment-target" value="***" />` in your `config.xml`. Depending on the version of `cordova-ios` you're using would also effect how the Xcode project gets build. Make sure the version of `cordova-ios` is compatibly with your version of Xcode.

- No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: aps-environment.

And for this error, it would seem you don't have the entitlement set on your provisioning profile under your developer account. Go to [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com), log in, and find your app. There should be an edit button where you can change the entitlements. Its probably the one for Push Notifications. This can also be done in new versions of Xcode directly in the Capabilities tab.

Comment: That seemed to be the issue! Thanks! :)